# SQL: filtering on one JOIN while sorting on another

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a `Product` model that has many `Sku`s, and each product can also have a `Customization` that includes being featured. Schema looks like this:

```
Product
| id | category_id | title | image |

Sku
| id | product_id | subtitle | price |

Customization
| id | product_id | title | featured |
```

I'm filtering/sorting the `Product` based on its category_id and the prices of its `Sku`s like so:

```
SELECT id, title, image, prices
  FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.title, p.image, array_agg(s.price) as prices
    FROM "Products" p
    JOIN "Skus" s
    ON p.id = s.product_id
    WHERE p.category_id in (1,2,3,4) AND s.price > 99
    GROUP BY p.id
  ) x
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I'd like to add an additional filter for `Product`s whose `Customization`s have `featured = true`.

Is it possible to include another `JOIN` to do this, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need the subquery.  Second you can do this with a `JOIN` (or `IN` or `EXISTS`):

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.image, array_agg(s.price) as prices
FROM "Products" p JOIN
     "Skus" s
      ON p.id = s.product_id JOIN
      Customization c
      ON p.id = c.product_id AND c.featured = true
WHERE p.category_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) AND s.price > 99
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great and improves my original query as well!